# knitr kable and "*"

Tags: r, knitr, kable

I am trying to produce a table with a "*" as a value in a cell:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "James Durant"
date: "November 7, 2017"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r arthmatic, echo=FALSE}
library(knitr)
dfx <- data.frame(
  Operator = c("+", "-", "*", "/", "^", "**", "%%", "%/%"),
  Operation = c("addition", "subtraction", "multiplication", 
                "division", "exponentiation", "exponentiation",
                "modulus", "integer division")
  )
kable(dfx, escape = FALSE)
```
````

But the * and the ** does not appear in the table:
[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace each `*` with `\\text{*}` or `\\textasteriskcentered`

Comment: Just FRT, package{kableExtra} changes this behaviour, so you can directly tabulate asterisks in kable-build LaTeX tables. Caveat: you'll need to include more formatting, e.g. `booktabs = TRUE`.